# SQL Query rawQuery with PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Tags: php, mysql, php-mysqlidb

I'm using PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class (MysqliDb.php).

I have got that query, but Wamp says:

Fatal error: Problem preparing query

```
 SELECT car_id FROM gm_cars WHERE car_id NOT IN 
( 
  SELECT reserve_car_id FROM gm_reservations 
 WHERE reserve_dropOff > ? AND reserve_dropOff = ? AND reserve_pickUp )
```

Erreur de syntaxe près de '' à la ligne 1 in 
     `C:\wamp\www\work\libs\PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class-master\MysqliDb.php` on line 823

Query:
Connect to database

```
>$carsBetweenDates = $db->rawQuery
('SELECT car_id FROM gm_cars WHERE car_id NOT IN 
   (SELECT reserve_car_id FROM gm_reservations 
     WHERE reserve_dropOff > ? AND reserve_dropOff <= ? 
     UNION 
     DISTINCT SELECT reserve_car_id FROM gm_reservations 
      WHERE reserve_pickUp >= ? AND reserve_pickUp < ?)', 
      Array('2014-12-20 20:00:00', '2014-12-22 20:00:00', 
      '2014-12-20 20:00:00', '2014-12-22 20:00:00'));
```

I don't see the error. Thanks so much. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling the function like this:

```
$db->rawQuery('QUERY', array(), FALSE);
```

I think the sanitizing damages your query ( it may strip html characters, in your case the < > conditions )

Assuming this is the class:
https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php

Answer (score 0):

Try change the query in order to simplify it. First of all you join the two tables into one, and then invert the conditions to remove partially the "NOT IN"

```
SELECT gm_cars.car_id 
FROM gm_cars LEFT JOIN gm_reservations
ON gm_cars.car_id = gm_reservations.reserve_car_id
WHERE (reserve_dropOff <= ? OR reserve_dropOff > ?)
    AND (reserve_pickUp < ? OR reserve_pickUp >= ?)
    AND gm_cars.car_id NOT IN Array('...')
GROUP BY gm_cars.car_id
```

One more thing, I assume that you are going to replace the "?" with values in the final query, if you want a more generic query you can do something like this:(example in PHP)

```
$queryStaff = "SELECT STAFF.id FROM STAFF WHERE name = '" . $your_variable . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

an example.

```
$db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM print_orders WHERE print_guests.id = print_orders.id AND print_order_products.order_id = print_orders.id AND  print_orders.id = ? AND print_guests.email = ?  AND print_order_products.order_id = ? " , array($_POST['orden'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['orden']));
```